# Why is using the Python mmap module much slower than calling POSIX mmap from C++?

Tags: python, c++, performance, posix, mmap

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;
#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main() {
    timeval tv1, tv2, tv3, tve;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, 0);
    int size = 0x1000000;
    int fd = open("data", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, FILE_MODE);
    ftruncate(fd, size);
    char *data = (char *) mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = 'S';
    }
    munmap(data, size);
    close(fd);
    gettimeofday(&tv2, 0);
    timersub(&tv2, &tv1, &tve);
    printf("Time elapsed: %ld.%06lds\n", (long int) tve.tv_sec, (long int) tve.tv_usec);
}
```

Python code:

```py
import mmap
import time

t1 = time.time()
size = 0x1000000

f = open('data/data', 'w+')
f.truncate(size)
f.close()

file = open('data/data', 'r+b')
buffer = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)

for i in xrange(size):
    buffer[i] = 'S'

buffer.close()
file.close()
t2 = time.time()
print "Time elapsed: %.3fs" % (t2 - t1)
```

I think these two program are the essentially same since C++ and Python call the same system call(`mmap`).

But the Python version is much slower than C++'s:

```
Python: Time elapsed: 1.981s
C++:    Time elapsed: 0.062143s
```

**Could any one please explain the reason why the mmap Python of is much slower than C++?**

---

Environment:

C++:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
```

Python:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)
```

Comment: What is execution time for the same program with empty `for i in xrange(size): x++` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not `mmap` is slower, but the filling of a array with values. Python is known, to be slow on doing primitive operations. Use higher-level operations:

```
buffer[:] = 'S' * size
```

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on what @Daniel said – any Python operation has more overhead (in some cases *way* more, like orders of magnitude) than the comparable amount of code implementing a solution in C++.

The loop filling the buffer is indeed the culprit – but also the `mmap` module itself has a lot more housekeeping to do than you might think, despite that it  offers an interface whose semantics are, misleadingly, verrrry closely aligned with POSIX `mmap()`. You know how POSIX `mmap()` just tosses you a `void*` (which you just have to use `munmap()` to clean up after it, at some point)? Python’s `mmap` has to allocate a `PyObject` structure to babysit the `void*` – making it conform to Python’s buffer protocol by furnishing metadata and callbacks to the runtime, propagating and queueing reads and writes, maintaining GIL state, cleaning up its allocations no matter what errors occur…

All of that stuff takes time and memory, too. I personally don’t ever find myself using the `mmap` module, as it doesn’t give you a clear-cut advantage on any I/O problem, like out-of-the-box – you can just as easily use `mmap` to make things slower as you might make them faster.

*Contrastingly I often *do* find that using POSIX* `mmap()` *can be VERY advantageous when doing I/O from within a Python C/C++ extension (provided you’re minding the GIL state), precisely because coding around* `mmap()` *avoids all that Python internal-infrastructure stuff in the first place.*

Comment: _Contrastingly I often *do* find that using POSIX mmap() can be VERY advantageous_  Could you provide a simple use case example of this?

Comment: @Greg sure: when random – as in arbitrary – access to file contents is necessary (and more important than incremental I/O performance). Under the hood, Python 2 used standard C streams (i.e. FILE*) and double-buffered everything; Python 3 ditches those for a dead-simple descriptor-based I/O scheme and implements buffering and all the incremental stuff in Python itself… both stratagems force an I/O bottleneck for algorithms that need to do random-access (such as one finds in e.g. image-processing or machine-learning).